# How to implement bfcache in Chrome so page returns to same DOM state after back navigation

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, browser-cache, bfcache

I’m trying to make Chrome implement bfcache (back-forward cache), which “[stores](https://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history) the current state of the DOM in memory. When a page is re-visited via the back button, no requests are made. The DOM itself is served straight up from cache.” My understanding is that both Safari and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) use some form of bfcache, but not the current version of Chrome. Basically, I want a few simple jQuery animations to resume where they left off after navigating back to the page after clicking on a link. They work as intended in Safari, but not in Chrome. Here is the basic script I want to freeze and resume upon back navigation:

```js
var soundControl = document.getElementById(“song”); 
  $(“#song”).get(0).play();

$(‘div.a img’).fadeIn(500);
$(‘div.b img’).delay(750).fadeIn(500);
$(‘div.c img’).delay(1500).fadeIn(500);
$(‘div.d img’).delay(2250).fadeIn(500);
```

The solution may involve adding an EventListener or using the persisted property, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward to 2019 - Chrome is actually testing bfcache implementation. The works are still in progress and expected to be released next year (2020)

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/OVROmzNUng0/1gTmi-I3EQAJ